# Sass doc is giving me duplicate results

Tags: sass

My output tree is showing duplicates and I can't figure out why. This is prototype angular project with this file tree. I can't figure out why.

src

- app
- - components
- scss
  styles.scss

Here's my out put tree
[image]

My sassdoc.json config

```
{
  "basePath": "https://mjhandy.github.io/AngularBoilerPlate/docs/sass/",
  "package": {
    "title": "Angular Boilerplate",
    "name": "ngBoilerplate",    
    "description": "My boilerplate for basic, resuable, Angular components"
  },  
  "dest": "./docs/sassdoc",
  "excliude": [
    "./src/scss/_mixins.scss"
  ],
  "groups" : {
    "structure" :       "Structure",
    "component" :       "Component",
    "helpers" :         "Helpers",
    "global" :          "Global Items",
    "mixins" :          "Mixins"
  },
  "options": {
    "display": {
      "watermark":  false
    }
  }

}
```

My run commands :

```
sassdoc ./src/**/* -c sassdoc.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same result with the following command within my `package.json` scripts

```
sassdoc 'src/assets/styles/sass/**'
```

According to the official [sassdoc documentation](http://sassdoc.com/getting-started/) they are using [this](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) library to parse glob patterns.

The `**` notation matches the directory itself, its containing files and its subdirectories.

But the root directory name is suffice for the sassdoc, it will iterate over its tree structure if any.

```
sassdoc 'src/assets/styles/sass/*'
# or simply
sassdoc 'src/assets/styles/sass'
```